# Getting unexpected identifier after adding ReCaptcha

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am getting an error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

on Line  33

This is after adding Google ReCaptcha to my `AJAX` contact form. I have reviewed this but I cannot seem to figure out what am I missing.

Maybe a fresh pair of eyes can spot my error?

**JS:**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#loader").fadeOut("slow");
    $('#main').fadeIn("slow");
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            element.removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        }
    });
      $('#emailForm').validate( {
        submitHandler : function(form) {
            return false;
        },
        rules : {
            userEmail:{
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            userName:{
                required : true,
                minlength : 3,
                maxlength : 50
            },
            subject: {
                required : true,
                minlength : 10
            },
            message: {
                required : true,
                minlength : 50
            }
        recaptcha_response_field: {
            required: true,
            checkCaptcha: true
          },
        },
        messages : {
            userEmail:{
                required : "Please enter your Email"
            },
        recaptcha_response_field: {
            checkCaptcha: "Your Captcha response was incorrect. Please try again."
          },
            userName:{
                required : "Please enter your name"
            },
            subject: {
                required : "Please enter your contact purpose",
                minlength : "Minimum length of subject must be 10 chars long."
            },
            message: {
                required : "Please enter your sweet message",
                minlength : "Minimum length of your message must be 50 chars long."
            }
        },
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            $(element).closest('div.form-group').find('.help-block').html(error.html());
        },
        highlight : function(element) {
            $(element).closest('div.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
             $(element).closest('div.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
             $(element).closest('div.form-group').find('.help-block').html('');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#sendMailBtn', function(e){



        e.preventDefault();
        if( $('#emailForm').valid() ) {
            var sendMailBtn = $('#sendMailBtn');
            sendMailBtn.button('loading');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.php',
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data : { data:
                  JSON.stringify($('#emailForm').serializeObject())
                  recaptcha_challenge_field: Recaptcha.get_challenge()
                  recaptcha_response_field: Recaptcha.get_response()
                },
                captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse(),
                success: function( response ){
                  (resp) ->
                    if resp is "true"
                    isCaptchaValid = true
                      else
                        Recaptcha.reload()
                        )
                          return isCaptchaValid
                          ), ""
                    sendMailBtn.button('reset');
                    $('input,textarea').val('');
                    showSuccessMessage();
                },
                error: function( response ) {
                    sendMailBtn.button('reset');
                    if( response.status === 400 || response.status === 403 || response.status === 500 ) {
                        showWarningMessage(response.responseJSON.message);
                    } else {
                        showWarningMessage();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });

    function showSuccessMessage(){
        swal({
            title: "Many Thanks!!!",
            text: "Thanks for contacting us, We will get back to your inbox shortly...",
            type: "success",
            html: true
            /*imageUrl: "img/thumbs-up.jpg"*/
        });
    }

    function showWarningMessage(message){
        if(typeof message === 'undefined' || message === '' ) message = "Something went wrong, Please try again.";
        swal({
            title: "Oops...",
            text: message,
            type: "error",
            html: true
        });
    }

    $.fn.serializeObject = function()
    {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function() {
            if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$response = [
    'status' => 'success',
    'message' => 'Mail sent successfully',
    'data' => []
];



//Checking is it ajax request
if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest') {
    //Invalid Ajax request
    http_response_code(403);
    $response = [
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Invalid request, please try again.',
        'data' => []
    ];
    responseHandler($response);
}

if( !isset($_POST['data']) ) {
    http_response_code(400);
    $response = [
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Empty post data.',
        'data' => []
    ];
    responseHandler($response);
}
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true); $errors = '';

//Email validation
if ( isset($data["userEmail"]) && !empty( $data["userEmail"] ) ) {
    $email = trim($data["userEmail"]);
    if ( filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
        $errors .= "$email is <strong>NOT</strong> a valid email address.<br/>";
    }
} else {
    $errors .= 'Please enter your email address.<br/>';
}
//Name Validation
if ( isset($data["userName"]) && !empty( $data["userName"] ) ) {
    $name = trim( $data["userName"] );
    if ( filter_var($name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) === false){
        $errors .= 'Please enter a valid name.<br/>';
    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
        $errors .= 'Only letters and white space allowed for name...<br/>';
    }
} else {
    $errors .= 'Please enter your name.<br/>';
}

//Subject Validation
if ( isset($data["subject"]) && !empty( $data["subject"] ) ) {
    $subject = trim( $data["subject"] );
    if ( filter_var($subject, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) === false){
        $errors .= 'Please enter a subject to send.<br/>';
    }
} else {
    $errors .= 'Please enter a subject to send.<br/>';
}

//Message Validation
if ( isset($data["message"]) && !empty( $data["message"] ) ) {
    $message = trim( $data["message"] );
    if ( filter_var($message, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) === false){
        $errors .= 'Please enter a message to send.<br/>';
    }
} else {
    $errors .= 'Please enter a message to send.<br/>';
}

//Google ReCaptcha
if ( isset($_POST["captcha"]) ) {

        require('component/recaptcha/src/autoload.php');

        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(SECRET_KEY, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\SocketPost());

        $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['captcha'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

            if (!$resp->isSuccess()) {
                        $errors .= 'Captcha is required.<br/>';
            }
}

if(!empty( $errors )) {
    http_response_code(400);
    $response = [
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => $errors,
        'data' => []
    ];
    responseHandler($response);
}

//Filtering out newlines in the email subject
$subject = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$subject);
$contactContent = file_get_contents('email_templates/contact.html');;
$parameters = ['name' => $name, 'to_name' => TO_NAME, 'message' => $message ];

if(! send_mail( $email, $subject, $contactContent, $parameters ) ){
    //Email sent failed.
    http_response_code(500);
    $response = [
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Email service failing temporarily Or Maybe you are entered invalid E-mail, Please enter valid email and try again.',
        'data' => []
    ];
    responseHandler($response);
} else {
    //Email successfully sent
    http_response_code(200);
    responseHandler($response);
}

/**
 * responseHandler function
 * @param array $response request response
 */
function responseHandler($response)
{
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}

/**
 * send_mail function
 * @param  string $email             [[Description]]
 * @param  string $Subject           [[Description]]
 * @param  string $message           [[Description]]
 * @param  array [$parameters = []] [[Description]]
 * @return boolean  [[Description]]
 */

function send_mail($email, $Subject, $message, $parameters = []){
    ////Parse the message with given parameters
    if( !empty( $parameters ) )$message = parse($message, $parameters);



    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = SMTP_HOST;  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = SMTP_AUTH;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = SMTP_USERNAME;
    $mail->Password = SMTP_PASSWORD;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = SMTP_SECURE;                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = SMTP_PORT;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    if( isset($parameters['name']) )
        $mail->setFrom($email, $parameters['name']);
    else
        $mail->setFrom($email);


    $mail->addAddress(TO_EMAIL);     // Add a recipient
    //$mail->addReplyTo($email, 'Smart Invoice V3 Promotion');
    $mail->addBCC(TO_EMAIL);

    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $Subject;

    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($message);

    if(!$mail->send()) {//$mail->ErrorInfo;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


/**
 * parse function
 * @param  string $message    [[Description]]
 * @param  array $parameters [[Description]]
 * @return string [[Description]]
 */
function parse($message, $parameters) {
    foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
        $message = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $message);
    }
    return $message;
}
```

I have added the additional code into Javascript, to call upon the PHP script. The validation should be performed both on the client side and on the server side.

If there is an error with the captcha then an error is printed to the $errors string and then printed by the javascript.

Comment: Drop your JS into a site like `http://jshint.com/` ... it lists a lot of issues you should fix before continuing. There are sooooo many syntax issues in that code.